# One field fails to show up in tableView on MacOS

Tags: swift, nstableview, macos-sierra

In the code shown at [gist](https://gist.github.com/rpural/8d651ad318584d7b564e0e88f831e4c3), the first three fields show correctly in the window, but the fourth field is always blank, even though I can print the value of cell.textField!.stringValue just before returning the cell. I can't figure out what is wrong with this one field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not heard from anyone here, and based on the fact that I could see the correct output right up to the point where the cell was returned, I rebuilt a new storyboard from the ground up. The new storyboard and the original code combined to give a running, working program.

Sorry no one here could help. I thought there'd have been some sort of comment or direction, but sadly...

Comment: Sadly the question was too short. I had no idea what you're talking about. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)